# JavaScript or jQuery, how to find element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div data-name="countrySelectorRoot">
    <select>
        <option value="C1">Country 1</option>
        <option value="C2">Country 2</option>
        <option value="C3">Country 3</option>
        <option value="C4">Country 4</option>
        <option value="C5">Country 5</option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Some script which finds parent div...
    </script>
</div>
```

Inside script, I need code which needs to find my "countrySelectorRoot" div `(var MyRoot = // Code that finds element with data-name="countrySelectorRoot").`

However, I can have multiple divs with same data-name attribute and same contents,
but I need to find the the specific one which is the parent of the script.

How to do this?

Comment: why aren't you doing a css class or id?

Comment: Because I can have multiple same divs inside document, I need the specific one not all of them.

Comment: @Dusan, ok... but what makes one more specific that the other?

Comment: MV3 razor, I would not like to complicate with unique id or data attribute of the div if other solution is possible.

Comment: Is that `<div>` always an exact parent of `<script>` or it could be nested further? I think it would be best to use `id` either on `<div>` or `<script>`, otherwise it will be hard to even find the `<script>` selement from the script itself.

Comment: I know the solution with unique ID, however is there some other?

Comment: yes, there is another way to select an element within a class.  if i can not add the id attribute and only have access to classes, i make sure the element i'm targeting is in the same expected position.  i then use .index() to reference the element and process it with methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   $('div[data-name="countrySelectorRoot"][/Script]')
```

it shall select the the specific one which is the parent of the script.

Answer (score 0):

try `eq()` method:

```
$('div[data-name="countrySelectorRoot"]:eq(0)') // this selects first div
```

or `:has`:

```
$('div[data-name="countrySelectorRoot"]:has(script)')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea:

```
$('div script').parent()
```

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/udiyaw/2/edit)*

But I honestly think you're using javascript the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

To specifically target the one that has the script tag in it, use `:has` filter

```
$('[data-name="countrySelectorRoot"]:has(script)');
```